# multiple BETWEEN & multiple AND in mySql Query giving wrong answer

Tags: mysql

Here is my mysql query. What I want to extract is; all rows that is inserted in past 6 days including today too. Here is my query

```
    $user_ids = $_SESSION['user_ids']; //its array
    $cs_user_ids =implode(",",$user_ids);


  SELECT fb_user.name,schedule.id,schedule.location,schedule.arrival,
   schedule.departure,schedule.notes,schedule.lat,
   schedule.lon,schedule.who_can_c_me
  FROM schedule,fb_user
  WHERE    EXTRACT(DAY FROM arrival)
  BETWEEN  EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY))
  AND      EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURDATE())
  AND      EXTRACT(DAY FROM departure)
  BETWEEN  EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY))
  AND      EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURDATE())
  AND      fb_user.fb_id = schedule.fb_id 
  AND fb_user.fb_id IN($cs_user_ids)
```

I want `OR` here in place of `AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM departure)` in this very statment. Because I need either *arrival* or *departure* date but it's not working with `OR` it's working with `AND` and I don't need that. Whats awry in my query? I guess problem with `()`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this way using parenthesis bracket

```
"SELECT fb_user.name,schedule.id,schedule.location,schedule.arrival,schedule.departure,schedule.notes,schedule.lat,schedule.lon,schedule.who_can_c_me
  FROM schedule,fb_user
  WHERE    EXTRACT(DAY FROM arrival)
  (BETWEEN  EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY)) AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURDATE()))

  OR      
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM departure)
  (BETWEEN  EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY)) AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURDATE()))

  AND fb_user.fb_id = schedule.fb_id 
  AND fb_user.fb_id IN($cs_user_ids)"
```

Comment: I don't think this fulfills this: ***either arrival or departure date***. Does it?

Comment: woow now what wrong in the answer please suggest atleast if you giving -1 so correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
       fb_user.name,schedule.id,schedule.location,schedule.arrival,schedule.departure,
       schedule.notes,schedule.lat,schedule.lon,schedule.who_can_c_me
FROM 
       schedule,fb_user
WHERE    
    (
     (EXTRACT(DAY FROM arrival) BETWEEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY)) AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURDATE()))
     OR 
     (EXTRACT(DAY FROM departure) BETWEEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY)) AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURDATE()))
    )
  AND      
      fb_user.fb_id = schedule.fb_id 
  AND 
      fb_user.fb_id IN($cs_user_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT fb_user.name,schedule.id,schedule.location,schedule.arrival,schedule.departure,schedule.notes,schedule.lat,schedule.lon,schedule.who_can_c_me
  FROM schedule,fb_user
  WHERE ((DATE(arrival)  BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND CURDATE())
  OR (DATE(departure) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND CURDATE()))
  AND fb_user.fb_id = schedule.fb_id  AND fb_user.fb_id IN($cs_user_ids)
```

I think the use of Extract DAY will cause unexpected results with days like 1st or 2nd and this comparisons... avoid it.